# Как хранить имя базы данных и пусть к ней во Flask.g?

Tags: python, flask

я храню конфигурацию `flask` в отдельном файле `config`.
в отдельном модуле `tools.py` я храню функции для работы с базой данных, чтобы не засорять основной код.
в эти функции я передаю только объект `flask.g` и то, что нужно взять из базы.
всё подключение к базе тоже происходит в `tools.py`.
я хочу, чтобы у меня была константа `g.dbname` в которой я бы хранил имя базы.
если я пишу

```
app.app_context().push()
g.dbname = app.config['dbname']
```

то все работает, пока не произошло не одного подключения. после первого подключения он говорит, что

```
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'dbname'
```

как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

сам нашел решение, может, кому пригодится.
в функции, которая подключается к базе я делаю

```
import config
```

и добавляю необходимые данные к flask.g

```
g.dbname = config.dbname
```